# VSTS "Run Functional Tests" TestCategory Not Working With Specrun Tests

Tags: vstest, specrun, vstest.console.exe, vstest.console

I am trying to run a subset of our specrun tests as part of our VSTS release process.  It works fine with the "Visual Studio Test" step with TestCategory=SmokeTest:
[image: Visual Studio Test]

It finds 47 tests and executes them.  When I use the same configuration using the "Run Functional Tests" like so:
[image: Run Functional Tests]

I get the following output:

```
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z DistributedTests: Creating run for selected test assemblies with following parameters
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z DistributedTests: SourceFilter: **\*AcceptanceTests*.dll TestCaseFilter: TestCategory=SmokeTest
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z DistributedTests: Run title: Specflow Test Run
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z DistributedTests: is automated: True
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z ##[debug]DistributedTests: Test Machines Environment Url: dta://env/_Project/_apis/32858/201705221310348402
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z DistributedTests: test settings id : 8585
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z DistributedTests: build location: C:\TestDrop\AcceptanceTests-SpecFlow
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z DistributedTests: build id: 32858
2017-05-22T13:12:01.3937396Z DistributedTests: test configuration mapping: 
2017-05-22T13:12:01.7387150Z DistributedTests: Test Run with Id 23835 Queued
2017-05-22T13:12:01.9137365Z DistributedTests: Test run '23835' is in 'InProgress' state.
2017-05-22T13:12:12.0518938Z DistributedTests: Test run '23835' is in 'InProgress' state.
2017-05-22T13:12:22.1867837Z DistributedTests: Test run '23835' is in 'InProgress' state.
2017-05-22T13:12:32.3244144Z DistributedTests: Test run '23835' is in 'InProgress' state.
2017-05-22T13:12:42.4917165Z DistributedTests: Test run '23835' is in 'InProgress' state.
2017-05-22T13:12:52.6228617Z DistributedTests: Test run '23835' is in 'InProgress' state.
2017-05-22T13:13:02.7562848Z DistributedTests: Test run '23835' is in 'Aborted' state.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.7604691Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.7604691Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z Test Run queued for Project Collection Build Service (vsts).
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z 
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test discovery started.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: Test discovery started.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Aborted . Test run id : 23835
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Aborted . Test run id : 23835
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Error : SpecRun: discovered 101 from C:\TestDrop\AcceptanceTests-SpecFlow\.AcceptanceTests.dll
2017-05-22T13:13:12.8654238Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning]DistributedTests: Error : SpecRun: discovered 101 from C:\TestDrop\AcceptanceTests-SpecFlow\.AcceptanceTests.dll
```

It is discovering 101 tests, the total rather than just the ones marked as SmokeTest and it's not even running them.  It just bails out.  I know both VSTS steps are using vstest.console.exe.  Is there some other configuration I am missing?

Comment: Could you post the call of the vstest.console.exe with all parameters from the logs?

Comment: Please also send an e-Mail with this issue to support@specflow.org.

Comment: I added the output from the logs with the vstest.console.exe parameters

Comment: Just to let anyone else who is encountering the same error know, I just got an email from specflow support that this is due to a bug that they will be fixing.